# How can I create xslt-transformer with JAVA config in Spring integration?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, spring-integration

I have the following xslt-transformer in Spring-Integration. How can I do the same configuration with Java Config?

```
<si-xml:xslt-transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="output"
                         xsl-resource="classpath:/test.xsl"
                         result-transformer="resultToDoc"/>
```

Comment: What is "java config"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
@Bean
public XsltPayloadTransformer transformer() {
    return new XsltPayloadTransformer(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/test.xsl"),
            resultToDoc());
}
```

From other side consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl), where the same will me much simpler:

```
@Value("classpath:/test.xsl")
private Resource xsl;

.transform(Transformers.xslt(this.xsl))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="input")
@Bean
public MessageHandler xsltt() {
    MessageTransformingHandler handler = new MessageTransformingHandler(transformer());
    handler.setOutputChannelName("output");
    return handler;
}

@Bean
public Transformer transformer() {
    return new XsltPayloadTransformer(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/test.xsl"),
            resultToDoc());
}
```